# not able to send mail from Iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController { //....yor variables }
```

in ViewController.m file:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Sample Email Application"; // title of navigation bar

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(composeMail:)] autorelease]; // for adding a compose button //in navigation bar. //...your code }

-(void) composeMail: (id) sender{ 
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [picker setSubject:@"Sample Email Application"];
    [picker setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Visit for more help %@. ",@"http://google.com"] isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error { 
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: r u sending from the simulator ?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: yes i am sending from my simulator @ Aravindhanarvi

Comment: @Daniel A. White evevything is perfect but when i am cliking on send button then there is message body coming with to:  CC: Bcc: and message body along with cancel and send option buttons on upper side of toolbar but when i am cliking on send, not responding.
i have imported:
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
in my .H File

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the -setToRecipients, which you can't send mail unless you have an address to send to.

```
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"your@emailstring.com", nil]];
```

Comment: do you mean to say -(void)setToRecipients method or what?

Comment: That is the one yes. You need to set who the message is going to... then it should simulate a send event.

Comment: sir i am very new to iphone development could you please explain me in detail..@Bill Brasky

Comment: otherwise give your Skype-id or gmail-id  i want to discuss with you something which is related to iphone development  @Bill Brasky
thanks in Advance.